# Searching for text for studying Spectral sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, textbook-recommendation

I'm a graduate student studying algebraic geometry
I saw Spectral sequence is important in deformation theory, and many other places in algebraic geometry.
Can you recommand me some good text for studying Spectral sequence, focused on algebraic geometric purpose.

Comment: Griffith and Harris has a quick intro.

Comment: This reference is specific to algebraic topology rather than algebraic geometry, but I don't think you can do better than the third chapter of Bott and Tu's "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" if you want to understand what spectral sequences are and how to use them.

Comment: There's always "You could have invented spectral sequences" http://www.ams.org/notices/200601/fea-chow.pdf

Comment: There are beautiful notes by Tom Weston, http://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/SeminarOnCohomology/infres.pdf

Comment: Weibel's book on homological algebra has a nice chapter on Spectral sequences with exercises (and doesn't rely much on the earlier chapters).

Comment: "A user's guide to spectral sequnces" by John McCleary is a very thorough discussion of this topic. Don't know if it's good to start with.

Comment: Ravi Vakil's notes on algebraic geometry have a great section on those...(section 2.7). The rest of the book is also amazing by the way.

Link to the notes:
http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice is to first understand the spectral sequence associated to a filtered complex, beginning with a filtration of length one, then a filtration of length two .... These will be very concrete and you'll be able to write everything down, chase the relevant diagrams and see what's going on.

Then generalize by understanding the spectral sequence of a arbitrary exact couple, and you'll have a quite clear picture of most of the subject.

The definitions are in any book on homological algebra (I like Chapter 10 of Rotman), but the first thing you should do with these definitions is specialize to the simple cases (e.g. filtrations of length one) and write down all the relevant diagrams.